# List styling - second line indent when using counter

Tags: html, list, css, html-lists

I have a problem in the 2nd line indent when using custom counter..

I could not use 'list-style-type:decimal' as it doesnt give numbering as below.

```
1  first
2  second
   2.1 second.one ..... .. .. 
   But INDEDNT lost when spilled to second line
   2.2 second.two
3  Three
```

So I am using a custom counter, which gives me desired numbering, the issue is only with the 2nd line indent.

Please check my problem in [PEN here](http://codepen.io/Durai/pen/oxgPqj?editors=1100)

```
  ol {
    counter-reset: ci-counter;
    list-style-postion: inside;
    list-style-type: none;
    padding-left: 0px;
    margin-top: 0;
    margin-bottom: 11px;
  }

  ol li:before {
    content: counters(ci-counter, ".")"  ";
    counter-increment: ci-counter;
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Edit your HTML like this

```css
.img-cntr {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0 10px 10px 0;
    float:left;
}

ol {
    counter-reset: ci-counter;
    list-style-postion:inside;
    list-style-type: none;
    padding-left: 0px;
    margin-top: 0;
    margin-bottom: 11px;
}

ol li:before {
  content: counters(ci-counter, ".") "  ";
  counter-increment: ci-counter;
}
```

```html
<div class="cntr" style="width:40%">
      <div class="img-cntr">
        <image src="http://www.hdwallpapery.com/static/images/image5_170127819_PxgeF3V.jpg" height="200px"/>
      </div>
      
      <ol>
      <li>On average every day, across the organisation</li>
      <li>we spend at hours a day on the phone
        <ol><li>test</li></ol>
      </li>
      <li>to the IT Service Desk, with average wait times per</li>
     </ol>
      
    </div>
```

Comment: Hi, Did my solution help you?

Answer (score 1):

```
ul li{
    padding: 10px 0 10px 20px;
    text-indent: -1em;
}
```

this should move the text away from the counter